# Problem installing pullquote package

Tags: errors, packages, pullquote

I'm trying to install `pullquote` package using terminal. But it cannot be installed. I used different  repositories but it couldn't be installed. Here is the error:

```
tlmgr install pullquote
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TLDownload::get_file: response error: 404 Not Found (for http://................)
TLUtils::download_file: persistent connection ok, but download failed: http://.....................
TLUtils::download_file: retrying with wget.
TLUtils::download_file: retry with wget failed: 
http://......................
TLDownload::get_file: response error: 404 Not Found (for http://)
TLUtils::download_file: persistent connection ok, but download failed: http://..........................
TLUtils::download_file: retrying with wget.
TLUtils::download_file: retry with wget succeeded: 
http://........................
tlmgr: Cannot load TeX Live database from http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/
```

dots are some links.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't install packages with tlmgr that aren't on CTAN.